# How to create Http request with header and body format x-www-form-urlencoded and get the cookies value in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, cookies, httprequest, restsharp, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm trying to make an http request with the following attributes

1. Header - contains a key 'Referer' with a set value
2. Body format is x-www-form-urlencoded
3. Body contains multiple keyes 'type', 'encpwd', 'user', 'pwd' & 'admsid'

In the response from the request, I need to obtain values in the cookies. I'm able to do it via Postman get the cookies, however I need to write a function/method to achieve this and return the cookies values which will be required to authenticate in future API calls.

From the internet, I found a sample code as below

```
Dim client As RestSharp.RestClient = New RestSharp.RestClient(inEndpoint)
client.Timeout = 10000
client.CookieContainer = New System.Net.CookieContainer

Dim request As RestSharp.RestRequest = New RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.Post)
request.AddHeader("Referer", strReferer)

Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
responsecode=response.StatusCode
responsecontent=response.Content

Dim cookies =client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(response.ResponseUri)
cookiecontainer=cookies.ToString

Console.WriteLine("cookieJar "+ cookies.ToString)
Console.WriteLine("response Uri "+response.ResponseUri.ToString)
```

But when I'm trying this code in Visual Studio (I have installed RestSharp package already), I'm getting lots of error as below:

```
client.Timeout = 10000  -- Timeout is not a member of RestClient

client.CookieContainer = New System.Net.CookieContainer -- Property 'CookieContainer' is 'Read-Only'

Dim request As RestSharp.RestRequest = New RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.Post) -- Type 'RestRequest' is not defined

request.AddHeader("Referer", strReferer) -- 'AddHeader' is not a member of 'RestRequest'

Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request) -- Type 'IRestResponse' is not defined
```

I'm quite new to https request, please help me where I'm making mistake. Also I don't know/find how to add the body parameters with x-www-form-urlencoded format, everywhere it's mentioned in JSON, but this API service only accepts this format for Body.

Thanks for the help in advance.

I've tried the below code

```
Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient(endPoint)
Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest(Method.Post)
request.AddHeader("Referer", strReferer)
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "type=" + strType + "&encpwd= " + strEncPwd + "&user=" + strUser + "&pwd=" + strPwd + "&admsid=" + stradmsID, ParameterType.RequestBody)
Dim response = client.Execute(request)
```

It generates exception "cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code ran successfully.

```
    Dim client = New RestClient(endPoint)
    Dim request = New RestRequest()
    request.Method = Method.Post
    request.AddHeader("Referer", strReferer)
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.AddParameter("type", strType)
    request.AddParameter("encpwd", strEncPwd)
    request.AddParameter("user", strUser)
    request.AddParameter("pwd", strPwd)
    request.AddParameter("admsid", stradmsID)
    Dim response = client.Execute(request)
    Dim cookies = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(response.ResponseUri)
    Console.WriteLine("cookieJar " + cookies.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content)
```

Hope it will help someone. Thanks